# Hide "Update" item on wordpress admin menu

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to hide this item in the admin:

[image]

I have already removed the updated message using this:

```
add_action('admin_menu','wphidenag');
    function wphidenag() {
remove_action( 'admin_notices', 'update_nag', 3 );
}
```

But I haven't found a solution to this item, any ideas to do it the proper way, not with css?

Answer (score 0):

Done some googling. You could try this method:

http://developersmind.com/2010/06/12/preventing-wordpress-from-checking-for-updates-for-a-plugin/?replytocom=81

Comment: I have done a lot of googling. I founded this before BUT this doesn't hide the menu option, just stops wordpress from looking for plugins update. If it doesn't even have a update. the Update in the menu also appears